# React JS - How can you unveil a text form upon selecting a radio option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, radio-button

**Context:**

[image: Design Image]

**Problem:**

As you can see from the image, the user has two options and I only wish to unveil the "Prefix" input box if the user selects "Yes, set prefix". To provide further context, the user's input will later be used to generate a live preview as shown on the right-hand side of the image. Ant Design doesn't seem to have an example that relates to this specific situation and I'm trying to get better with React JS so any insights would be greatly appreciated. Even if you could point me to resources that would be awesome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add state to your component, add an onChange event to your component, update the state using setState inside the onChange function, guard the input field with the state value so that it only shows when it evaluates to being true. The render will re-trigger automatically when the onChange is fired and calls setState (react triggers re-renders on state change). Below is semi-pseudo code:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showPrefixField: false;
  }

updateShowPrefix(event) {
  const newValue = event.currentTarget.value === 'yes' ? true : false; //ternary statement sets boolean to true when they click on yes
  this.setState({showPrefixField: newValue}); // update state with true/false
}

render() {
  <input type="radio" onChange={this.updateShowPrefix} value='yes' />
  <input type="radio" onChange={this.updateShowPrefix} value='no' />

  //the line below is a guard condition meaning anything following the ampersands will only execute if its true
  {this.state.showPrefixField && 
    <label>prefix:</label>
    <input type="text" name="prefixFeild" />
  }

}
```